# How to determine the best baseline model to perform hyperparameter tuning on in scikit learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, hyperparameters

I'm working on data where I'm trying different classification algorithms and see which one performs best as a baseline model. The code for that is as follows:

```
# Trying out different classifiers and selecting the best

## Creat list of classifiers we're going to loop through
classifiers = [
    KNeighborsClassifier(),
    SVC(),
    DecisionTreeClassifier(),
    RandomForestClassifier(),
    AdaBoostClassifier(),
    GradientBoostingClassifier()
    ]

classifier_names = [
    'kNN',
    'SVC',
    'DecisionTree',
    'RandomForest',
    'AdaBoost',
    'GradientBoosting'
]

model_scores = []

## Looping through the classifiers
for classifier, name in zip(classifiers, classifier_names):
    pipe = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
        ('selector', SelectKBest(k=len(X.columns))),
        ('classifier', classifier)])
    score = cross_val_score(pipe, X, y, cv=5, scoring='accuracy').mean()
    model_scores.append(score)
    print("Model score for {}: {}".format(name, score))
```

The output is:

```
Model score for kNN: 0.7472524440239673
Model score for SVC: 0.7896621728161464
Model score for DecisionTree: 0.7302148734267939
Model score for RandomForest: 0.779058799919727
Model score for AdaBoost: 0.7949635904933918
Model score for GradientBoosting: 0.7930712637252372
```

Turns out the best model is the `AdaBoostClassifier()`. I would normally pick the best baseline model and perform a `GridSearchCV` on it to further improve its baseline performance.

However, what if, hypothetically speaking, the model that performed best as a baseline model (in this case AdaBoost), only improves 1% through hyperparameter tuning while a model that initially performed not as well (for example the `SCV()`), would have more "potential", to improve through hyperparameter tuning (i.e. would improve by for example 4%) and would - after tuning - end up being the better model?

**Is there a way to know this "potential" beforehand, without performing a GridSearch for *all* classifiers?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to know for **100 % certain** before hyperparameter tuning which classifier will end up performing best on any given problem. However, in practice what Kaggle competitions have shown on tabular data classification problems (as opposed to text or image-based) is that in almost every case, a gradient-boosted decision tree-based model (like [XGBoost](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [LightGBM](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) works best. Given this, it's likely that `GradientBoosting` will perform better under hyperparamter tuning since it's [based off LightGBM](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html?highlight=boosted%20decision%20trees#gradient-boosting).

What you are doing in the above code is to use simply all default values of the hyper parameters and for those algorithms which are more sensitive to hyperparameter tuning, it's not necessarily indicative of the final (fine-tuned) performance, as you've suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are ways like Univariate, Bivariate and Multivariate analysis to look at the data and then decide which model you can start as baseline.

you can also use the sklearn way to choose the right estimator.

[image]

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html